# how can i send http post requests from Laravel to Strapi CMS via Strapi's API

Tags: laravel, api, http-post, guzzle, strapi

I tried sending post requests to the API in postman and it works fine. but i can't find a proper syntax of doing from Laravel, i tried following this tutorial from the Laravel documentation [Http-client](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client#request-data) so i tried this syntax

```
function sendRequest (Request $data) {
    $phonenumber = $data['number'];
    $name = $data['name'];

    $data2['data']['attributes'] = [
        [
            'phonenumber' => $phonenumber,
            'name' => $name
        ]
    ];
    
    Http::post('http://example.com/users', $data2);

}
```

didn't work.

here is the API's data structure

[image: json]

thanks in advance

Comment: you need to tell more about the Strapi post API

Comment: nobody is asking what Strapi is, I asked about API docs or something such as curl code

Comment: then there is something you are doing wrong, you are not providing enough information

Comment: Is there a way to do the post request to API with jQuery's Ajax?

Comment: show your code?

Answer (score -2):

I do not know if this will make a difference but you're missing a comma after value2 as per the syntax.

```
$response = Http::post('http://example.com/users', [
'name' => 'Steve',
'role' => 'Network Administrator', ]);
```

I'm rather new to laravel also and id love to know this fix too incase I need it in the future :D good luck!

Comment: That does not make a difference